# I want to get users information and Analyse from facebook ,by using C# language (windows form)

Tags: c#

I want to get users information and Analyse from facebook ,by using C# language (windows form)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what are you asking for? What I can infer is: How can I retrieve Facebook users information using a Windows form application written in C#?